# snmpd is not listening on port 161 on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

I have installed snmpd on my Ubuntu server via *apt-get install snmpd snmp*. Then I changed the line in /etc/default/snmpd

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid 0.0.0.0'
```

After that, I restarted the snmpd server(*/etc/init.d/snmpd restart*).  However, when I ran *netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "*, I don't see snmpd is listening on port 161.

I don't have any firewall which blocks that port.

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf].  Also, have you looked for an snmpd log file?  Is the `snmpd` process running?  What do you get if you run `netstat -nap|grep [pid-of-snmpd-process]`?

Comment: yes, it's running and process id is 23592.  sudo netstat -nap|grep 23592
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*                           23592/snmpd     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2985974  23592/snmpd

Comment: SNMP uses UDP, you'll not see any TCP sockets in listening state in netstat.. (UDP sockets is never in a listening state)

Answer (score 5):

User "nos" is correct; UDP bindings do not show up as "LISTEN" under "netstat".  Instead, you will see a line or two like the following, showing that "snmpd" is indeed ready to receive data on UDP port 161:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address  State  PID/Program name
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161    0.0.0.0:*               1785/snmpd      
udp6       0      0 ::1:161        :::*                    1785/snmpd
```

The "netstat" manpage has this to say about the "State" column:

> The state of the socket. Since there are no states in raw mode and usually no states used in UDP, this column may be left blank.

Thus, you would not expect to see the word "LISTEN" here.

---

From a practical perspective, however, there is one more thing that I'd like to note.  Often, the default Net-SNMP "snmpd.conf" configuration file limits incoming connections to only local processes.

**Default /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf**

```
#  Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
#agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161,tcp:161,tcp6:[::1]:161
```

Usually, the point of setting up "snmpd" is so that *another* machine can monitor it.  To accomplish this, make sure that the first line is commented out and that the second line is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd note. It saved my day. +1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it *is* listening on 161/UDP. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/snmpd):

> By default, snmpd listens for incoming SNMP requests on UDP port 161 on all IPv4 interfaces. However, it is possible to modify this behaviour by specifying one or more listening addresses as arguments to snmpd. A listening address takes the form:  `[<transport-specifier>:]<transport-address>`

Read the man page for more details